# xslt - adding new xml tags by modifying existing ones

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<update-all-attributes>
   <document name="http:blah">
      <price>115.00 USD</price>
      <brand_qty>10 A</brand_qty>
      <style_size>10 A_new in stock</style_size>
   </document>
</update-all-attributes>
```

Now I want 2 new fields - discounted_price which is 10% lower than price and an increased_price which is 10% higher than price and also strip the extra blank spaces in between the values of brand_qty and style_size using XSLT 1.0- so my xml after modifying with xslt should look like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<update-all-attributes>
   <document name="http:blah">
      <price>115.00 USD</price>
      <discounted_price>103.50 USD</discounted_price>
      <increased_price>126.50 USD</increased_price>
      <brand_qty>10A</brand_qty>
      <style_size>10A_newinstock</style_size>
   </document>
</update-all-attributes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start with an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying). This will copy all nodes as-is.

Then override the identity transform for those nodes you need to modify; in this case the `document` element.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<update-all-attributes>
    <document name="http:blah">
        <price>115.00 USD</price>
    </document>
</update-all-attributes>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <xsl:variable name="price" select="substring-before(normalize-space(price),' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currency" select="substring-after(normalize-space(price),' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="difference" select="number($price) * .10"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <discounted_price><xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($price - $difference,'#,###.00'),' ',$currency)"/></discounted_price>
            <increased_price><xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($price + $difference,'#,###.00'),' ',$currency)"/></increased_price>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<update-all-attributes>
   <document name="http:blah">
      <price>115.00 USD</price>
      <discounted_price>103.50 USD</discounted_price>
      <increased_price>126.50 USD</increased_price>
   </document>
</update-all-attributes>
```

Comment: @Daniel-Thanks, it works! If in the same XML I have 2 more elements like<brand_qty>10 A</brand_qty> and <style_size>10 A_new in stock</style_size>, how can I strip the extra spaces in between them and use the same xslt so that they will look like <brand_qty>10A </brand_qty> and<style_size>10A_newinstock</style_size>?

Comment: @Meow - Just add another template that matches `brand_qty|style_size` and use `translate(.,' ','')` to strip all spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="price">
      <xsl:variable name="price" select="number(substring-before(., ' '))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="margin" select="$price*0.1"/>
      <xsl:variable name="currency" select="substring-after(., ' ')"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <discounted_price>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($price - $margin, '###,###.00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', $currency)"/>
      </discounted_price>
      <increased_price>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($price + $margin, '###,###.00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', $currency)"/>
      </increased_price>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**<kbd>[`Demo`](http://xsltransform.net/bdxtr2)</kbd>**

Comment: @har07- Thanks, it works! If in the same XML I have 2 more elements like<brand_qty>10 A</brand_qty> and <style_size>10 A_new in stock</style_size>, how can I strip the extra spaces in between them and use the same xslt so that they will look like <brand_qty>10A </brand_qty> and<style_size>10A_newinstock</style_size>?